# Apache Tomcat 10.0 Silent Installation

Tags: windows, tomcat, nsis, procrun

Does anyone know how to install Apache Tomcat 10 silently on the commandline?

I have tried /S and it just doesn't work. It seems like nothing is running and I get no error, it just goes directly to another command prompt.

Without any arguments the installer comes up properly.

I want everything installed as default except for the windows service to be set to auto instead of manual.

Comment: Can you add the command line you are trying to use?

Comment: For the moment simply .exe /S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Installation using the Windows installer

Tomcat's Windows installer is an [NSIS installer](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page), therefore it supports the [standard /S](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusagecommon) command switch.

All other standard NSIS options also work, so if your want to install it in another folder, just execute in a `cmd` prompt:

```
tomcat-<version>.exe /S /D=D:\installation path\with spaces
```

The only non standard command line options are:

- `/?` which prints a nice usage message,
- `/C=config.ini`, which allows to set other variables in an `*.ini` file. The complete list of variables you can set can be found in [the source script](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/3bdd80293fb2b88a8b3df50692a93047261bd082/res/tomcat.nsi#L473).

#### Installation from zip archive

Tomcat installation sums up to:

- unpacking the files in a directory,
- installing the service.

Therefore you can download the *"64-bit Windows zip"* and unpack it.

The `Tomcat10.exe` executable in the `bin` folder is the executable used to install the service and it is actually a copy of [prunsrv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html). You can find the list of command line parameters in [its documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html#Command_line_parameters).

Instead of calling directly `prunsrv`, it is easier to use the `service.bat` script in the same folder:

```
set "SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE=auto"
service.bat install
```

There is no *"silent"* switch, but all the output is done by the script itself, so you can comment it out.

**Edit:** Although the `service.bat` script has only a couple of arguments available:

```
service.bat install/remove [service_name [--rename]] [--user username]
```

some parameters can be provided through environment variables:

- the standard `CATALINA_HOME`, `CATALINA_BASE`, `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`,
- the obsolete `JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS` to set the `java.endorsed.dirs` system property,
- `SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE` to choose the service's startup mode between `manual` (default), `delayed` or `auto`,
- `JvmMs` to set the initial memory pool size in MiB (default 128),
- `JvmMx` to set the maximum memory pool size in MiB (default 256).

Comment: Where do I get this service.bat file?

Comment: And does this also install tomcat application in addition to the service?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using the zip distribution instead of the Windows installer. I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay I grabbed the zip version and now I understand that the contents can just be dropped anywhere and one just needs to install the service to activate it via this service.bat file, but I still don't know WHERE to get the service.bat as it is not in the .zip.

Comment: Did you download the _"64-bit Windows zip"_ org _"32-bit Windows zip"_ from the [download page](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi)?

Comment: I grabbed the first item there listed as "zip".

Comment: I finally got this to kind of work but when I try to start the service, Tomcat immediately stops with nothing in the log files. Are there any Env Variables that I need to manually set up when installing via this method?

Comment: All I've done so far was place the contents of the zip file on my drive where I want tomcat installed (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-10.0.5) and used the service.bat install command to set up the service.

I tried to add JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME env variables but the thing still refuses to start. Did I miss something?

Comment: Check whether Java and Tomcat10.exe have the same architecture (both 32 or 64 bits): in an administrator `cmd` run `java -version` and `Tomcat10.exe //VS`.

Comment: Java 1.8.0_151 it's 32 bit. Tomcat says version 1.2.4.0/Win32
Just to let you know if I run the startup.bat the command window, I can see some logs and something die after a split second (in a second command window that it opens) but for some reason this never makes it to the log file. It happens too quickly for me to see it.

Comment: I got it. The base dir didn't exist because I had a bad path. But this SHOULD have shown in the log. Not sure why it didn't.

Comment: So I got this to run but it seems like it doesn't set the ${catalina.home} path right. I noticed it's because I have spaces in my paths for jre_home and catalina_home env variables. It seem to not properly handle the spaces. Any idea how I can get it to work? I can tell because no logs are being written to the CATALINA_HOME/logs folder.

Comment: You can look at the registry keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0` to check if spaces got messed up. If you used `set "CATALINA_HOME=..."` try `set CATALINA_HOME="..."`.

Comment: They all look fine in there. I'm judging by the fact that I can't get to any of my pages off of localhost (where I have defined in Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/page.xml) and the logs aren't being written. Both use ${catalina.home}. But I see -DCatalina.home set in the registry keys. That's why I assumed it was an env variable issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added a comment [on your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67629071/11748454). I tested a `CATALINA_BASE` with spaces and except a permission problem everything worked out.

Comment: You were spot on. It was the permissions not the env variables. Thanks Piotr! You are the man!